# Cant place outgoing call en E1

Tags: asterisk

I have Asterisk, dahdi and Libpri installed and configured. I now just had my E1 connection hooked to the Telco operator. My incoming calls are received perfectly, but no way to place an outgoing call.

Below the output of the Cli console (with intense debugging on) when I try to place a call:

```
root@gomobile-server:~# asterisk -rvvv
Privilege escalation protection disabled!
See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/x/1gKfAQ for more details.
Asterisk 11.7.0, Copyright (C) 1999 - 2013 Digium, Inc. and others.
Created by Mark Spencer <markster@digium.com>
Asterisk comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; type 'core show warranty' for detail                                                                             s.
This is free software, with components licensed under the GNU General Public
License version 2 and other licenses; you are welcome to redistribute it under
certain conditions. Type 'core show license' for details.
=========================================================================
Connected to Asterisk 11.7.0 currently running on gomobile-server (pid = 2316)
gomobile-server*CLI> pri intense debug span 1
Enabled debugging on span 1
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [0646121212@from-sip:1] Dial("SIP/602-00000000", "DAHDI/G0/0646121212") in new stack
PRI Span: 1 -- Making new call for cref 32769
    -- Requested transfer capability: 0x00 - SPEECH
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 > DL-DATA request
PRI Span: 1 > Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=36
PRI Span: 1 > TEI=0 Call Ref: len= 2 (reference 1/0x1) (Sent from originator)
PRI Span: 1 > Message Type: SETUP (5)
PRI Span: 1 TEI=0 Transmitting N(S)=0, window is open V(A)=0 K=7
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 > TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 > V(A)=0, V(S)=0, V(R)=0
PRI Span: 1 > K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 > T200_id=0, N200=3, T203_id=8192
PRI Span: 1 > [ 02 01 00 00 08 02 00 01 05 04 03 80 90 a3 18 03 a9 83 9f 6c 05 21 80 36 30 32 70 0b 80 30 36 34 36 31 32 31 32 31 32 a1 ]
PRI Span: 1 > Informational frame:
PRI Span: 1 > SAPI: 00  C/R: 1 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 >  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 > N(S): 000   0: 0
PRI Span: 1 > N(R): 000   P: 0
PRI Span: 1 > 36 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 > Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=36
PRI Span: 1 > TEI=0 Call Ref: len= 2 (reference 1/0x1) (Sent from originator)
PRI Span: 1 > Message Type: SETUP (5)
PRI Span: 1 > [04 03 80 90 a3]
PRI Span: 1 > Bearer Capability (len= 5) [ Ext: 1  Coding-Std: 0  Info transfer capability: Speech (0)
PRI Span: 1 >                              Ext: 1  Trans mode/rate: 64kbps, circuit-mode (16)
PRI Span: 1 >                                User information layer 1: A-Law (35)
PRI Span: 1 > [18 03 a9 83 9f]
PRI Span: 1 > Channel ID (len= 5) [ Ext: 1  IntID: Implicit  Other(PRI)  Spare: 0  Exclusive  Dchan: 0
PRI Span: 1 >                       ChanSel: As indicated in following octets
PRI Span: 1 >                       Ext: 1  Coding: 0  Number Specified  Channel Type: 3
PRI Span: 1 >                       Ext: 1  Channel: 31 Type: NET]
PRI Span: 1 > [6c 05 21 80 36 30 32]
PRI Span: 1 > Calling Party Number (len= 7) [ Ext: 0  TON: National Number (2)  NPI: ISDN/Telephony Numbering Plan (E.164/E.163) (1)
PRI Span: 1 >                                 Presentation: Presentation allowed, User-provided, not screened (0)  '602' ]
PRI Span: 1 > [70 0b 80 30 36 34 36 31 32 31 32 31 32]
PRI Span: 1 > Called Party Number (len=13) [ Ext: 1  TON: Unknown Number Type (0)  NPI: Unknown Number Plan (0)  '0646121212' ]
PRI Span: 1 > [a1]
PRI Span: 1 > Sending Complete (len= 1)
PRI Span: 1 -- Stopping T203 timer
PRI Span: 1 -- Starting T200 timer
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:6334 q931_setup: Call 32769 enters state 1 (Call Initiated).  Hold state: Idle
    -- Called DAHDI/G0/0646121212
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 < TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 < V(A)=0, V(S)=1, V(R)=0
PRI Span: 1 < K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 < T200_id=8192, N200=3, T203_id=0
PRI Span: 1 < [ 02 01 01 02 ]
PRI Span: 1 < Supervisory frame:
PRI Span: 1 < SAPI: 00  C/R: 1 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 <  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 < Zero: 0     S: 0 01: 1  [ RR (receive ready) ]
PRI Span: 1 < N(R): 001 P/F: 0
PRI Span: 1 < 0 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 -- Got ACK for N(S)=0 to (but not including) N(S)=1
PRI Span: 1 -- ACKing N(S)=0, tx_queue head is N(S)=-1 (-1 is empty, -2 is not transmitted)
PRI Span: 1 -- Stopping T200 timer
PRI Span: 1 -- Starting T203 timer
PRI Span: 1 Done handling message for SAPI/TEI=0/0
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 < TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 < V(A)=1, V(S)=1, V(R)=0
PRI Span: 1 < K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 < T200_id=0, N200=3, T203_id=8192
PRI Span: 1 < [ 00 01 00 02 08 02 80 01 02 18 03 a9 83 9f ]
PRI Span: 1 < Informational frame:
PRI Span: 1 < SAPI: 00  C/R: 0 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 <  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 < N(S): 000   0: 0
PRI Span: 1 < N(R): 001   P: 0
PRI Span: 1 < 10 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 < Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=10
PRI Span: 1 < TEI=0 Call Ref: len= 2 (reference 1/0x1) (Sent to originator)
PRI Span: 1 < Message Type: CALL PROCEEDING (2)
PRI Span: 1 < [18 03 a9 83 9f]
PRI Span: 1 < Channel ID (len= 5) [ Ext: 1  IntID: Implicit  Other(PRI)  Spare: 0  Exclusive  Dchan: 0
PRI Span: 1 <                       ChanSel: As indicated in following octets
PRI Span: 1 <                       Ext: 1  Coding: 0  Number Specified  Channel Type: 3
PRI Span: 1 <                       Ext: 1  Channel: 31 Type: NET]
PRI Span: 1 -- Got ACK for N(S)=1 to (but not including) N(S)=1
PRI Span: 1 -- T200 requested to stop when not started
PRI Span: 1 T203 requested to start without stopping first
PRI Span: 1 -- Starting T203 timer
PRI Span: 1 Received message for call 0x7fcc9c0015d0 on link 0x2ef8440 TEI/SAPI 0/0
PRI Span: 1 -- Processing IE 24 (cs0, Channel ID)
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:8831 post_handle_q931_message: Call 32769 enters state 3 (Outgoing Call Proceeding).  Hold state: Idle
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 > TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 > V(A)=1, V(S)=1, V(R)=1
PRI Span: 1 > K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 > T200_id=0, N200=3, T203_id=8192
PRI Span: 1 > [ 00 01 01 02 ]
PRI Span: 1 > Supervisory frame:
PRI Span: 1 > SAPI: 00  C/R: 0 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 >  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 > Zero: 0     S: 0 01: 1  [ RR (receive ready) ]
PRI Span: 1 > N(R): 001 P/F: 0
PRI Span: 1 > 0 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 Done handling message for SAPI/TEI=0/0
Span 1: Processing event PRI_EVENT_PROCEEDING(13)
    -- DAHDI/i1/0646121212-1 is proceeding passing it to SIP/602-00000000
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 < TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 < V(A)=1, V(S)=1, V(R)=1
PRI Span: 1 < K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 < T200_id=0, N200=3, T203_id=8192
PRI Span: 1 < [ 00 01 02 02 08 02 80 01 45 08 02 80 b9 ]
PRI Span: 1 < Informational frame:
PRI Span: 1 < SAPI: 00  C/R: 0 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 <  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 < N(S): 001   0: 0
PRI Span: 1 < N(R): 001   P: 0
PRI Span: 1 < 9 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 < Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=9
PRI Span: 1 < TEI=0 Call Ref: len= 2 (reference 1/0x1) (Sent to originator)
PRI Span: 1 < Message Type: DISCONNECT (69)
PRI Span: 1 < [08 02 80 b9]
PRI Span: 1 < Cause (len= 4) [ Ext: 1  Coding: CCITT (ITU) standard (0)  Spare: 0  Location: User (0)
PRI Span: 1 <                  Ext: 1  Cause: Bearer capability not authorized (57), class = Service or Option not Available (3) ]
PRI Span: 1 -- Got ACK for N(S)=1 to (but not including) N(S)=1
PRI Span: 1 -- T200 requested to stop when not started
PRI Span: 1 T203 requested to start without stopping first
PRI Span: 1 -- Starting T203 timer
PRI Span: 1 Received message for call 0x7fcc9c0015d0 on link 0x2ef8440 TEI/SAPI 0/0
PRI Span: 1 -- Processing IE 8 (cs0, Cause)
PRI Span: 1 -- Found active call: 0x7fcc9c0015d0 cref:32769
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:9084 post_handle_q931_message: Call 32769 enters state 12 (Disconnect Indication).  Hold state: Idle
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 > TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 > V(A)=1, V(S)=1, V(R)=2
PRI Span: 1 > K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 > T200_id=0, N200=3, T203_id=8192
PRI Span: 1 > [ 00 01 01 04 ]
PRI Span: 1 > Supervisory frame:
PRI Span: 1 > SAPI: 00  C/R: 0 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 >  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 > Zero: 0     S: 0 01: 1  [ RR (receive ready) ]
PRI Span: 1 > N(R): 002 P/F: 0
PRI Span: 1 > 0 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 Done handling message for SAPI/TEI=0/0
Span 1: Processing event PRI_EVENT_HANGUP_REQ(15)
    -- Span 1: Channel 0/31 got hangup request, cause 57
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:7135 q931_hangup: Hangup other cref:32769
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:6892 __q931_hangup: ourstate Disconnect Indication, peerstate Disconnect Request, hold-state Idle
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:5930 q931_release: Call 32769 enters state 19 (Release Request).  Hold state: Idle
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 > DL-DATA request
PRI Span: 1 > Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=9
PRI Span: 1 > TEI=0 Call Ref: len= 2 (reference 1/0x1) (Sent from originator)
PRI Span: 1 > Message Type: RELEASE (77)
PRI Span: 1 TEI=0 Transmitting N(S)=1, window is open V(A)=1 K=7
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 > TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 > V(A)=1, V(S)=1, V(R)=2
PRI Span: 1 > K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 > T200_id=0, N200=3, T203_id=8192
PRI Span: 1 > [ 02 01 02 04 08 02 00 01 4d 08 02 81 b9 ]
PRI Span: 1 > Informational frame:
PRI Span: 1 > SAPI: 00  C/R: 1 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 >  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 > N(S): 001   0: 0
PRI Span: 1 > N(R): 002   P: 0
PRI Span: 1 > 9 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 > Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=9
PRI Span: 1 > TEI=0 Call Ref: len= 2 (reference 1/0x1) (Sent from originator)
PRI Span: 1 > Message Type: RELEASE (77)
PRI Span: 1 > [08 02 81 b9]
PRI Span: 1 > Cause (len= 4) [ Ext: 1  Coding: CCITT (ITU) standard (0)  Spare: 0  Location: Private network serving the local user (1)
PRI Span: 1 >                  Ext: 1  Cause: Bearer capability not authorized (57), class = Service or Option not Available (3) ]
PRI Span: 1 -- Stopping T203 timer
PRI Span: 1 -- Starting T200 timer
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i1/0646121212-1'
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/602-00000000' status is 'CHANUNAVAIL'
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 < TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 < V(A)=1, V(S)=2, V(R)=2
PRI Span: 1 < K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 < T200_id=8192, N200=3, T203_id=0
PRI Span: 1 < [ 02 01 01 04 ]
PRI Span: 1 < Supervisory frame:
PRI Span: 1 < SAPI: 00  C/R: 1 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 <  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 < Zero: 0     S: 0 01: 1  [ RR (receive ready) ]
PRI Span: 1 < N(R): 002 P/F: 0
PRI Span: 1 < 0 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 -- Got ACK for N(S)=1 to (but not including) N(S)=2
PRI Span: 1 -- ACKing N(S)=1, tx_queue head is N(S)=-1 (-1 is empty, -2 is not transmitted)
PRI Span: 1 -- Stopping T200 timer
PRI Span: 1 -- Starting T203 timer
PRI Span: 1 Done handling message for SAPI/TEI=0/0
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 < TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 < V(A)=2, V(S)=2, V(R)=2
PRI Span: 1 < K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 < T200_id=0, N200=3, T203_id=8192
PRI Span: 1 < [ 00 01 04 04 08 02 80 01 5a ]
PRI Span: 1 < Informational frame:
PRI Span: 1 < SAPI: 00  C/R: 0 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 <  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 < N(S): 002   0: 0
PRI Span: 1 < N(R): 002   P: 0
PRI Span: 1 < 5 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 < Protocol Discriminator: Q.931 (8)  len=5
PRI Span: 1 < TEI=0 Call Ref: len= 2 (reference 1/0x1) (Sent to originator)
PRI Span: 1 < Message Type: RELEASE COMPLETE (90)
PRI Span: 1 -- Got ACK for N(S)=2 to (but not including) N(S)=2
PRI Span: 1 -- T200 requested to stop when not started
PRI Span: 1 T203 requested to start without stopping first
PRI Span: 1 -- Starting T203 timer
PRI Span: 1 Received message for call 0x7fcc9c0015d0 on link 0x2ef8440 TEI/SAPI 0/0
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:8944 post_handle_q931_message: Call 32769 enters state 0 (Null).  Hold state: Idle
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:7135 q931_hangup: Hangup other cref:32769
PRI Span: 1 q931.c:6892 __q931_hangup: ourstate Null, peerstate Null, hold-state Idle
PRI Span: 1 Destroying call 0x7fcc9c0015d0, ourstate Null, peerstate Null, hold-state Idle
PRI Span: 1
PRI Span: 1 > TEI: 0 State 7(Multi-frame established)
PRI Span: 1 > V(A)=2, V(S)=2, V(R)=3
PRI Span: 1 > K=7, RC=3, l3_initiated=0, reject_except=0, ack_pend=0
PRI Span: 1 > T200_id=0, N200=3, T203_id=8192
PRI Span: 1 > [ 00 01 01 06 ]
PRI Span: 1 > Supervisory frame:
PRI Span: 1 > SAPI: 00  C/R: 0 EA: 0
PRI Span: 1 >  TEI: 000        EA: 1
PRI Span: 1 > Zero: 0     S: 0 01: 1  [ RR (receive ready) ]
PRI Span: 1 > N(R): 003 P/F: 0
PRI Span: 1 > 0 bytes of data
PRI Span: 1 Done handling message for SAPI/TEI=0/0
Span 1: Processing event PRI_EVENT_HANGUP_ACK(9)
```

Here are some extracts from my configuration files:

/etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf

```
;autogenerated by /usr/sbin/wancfg_dahdi do not hand edit
;autogenrated on 2014-02-21
;Dahdi Channels Configurations 
;For detailed Dahdi options, view /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf.bak

[trunkgroups]

[channels]
context=default
usecallerid=yes
hidecallerid=no
callwaiting=yes
usecallingpres=yes
callwaitingcallerid=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
canpark=yes
cancallforward=yes
callreturn=yes
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
relaxdtmf=yes
rxgain=0.0
txgain=0.0
group=1
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
immediate=no
pridialplan=unknown

;Sangoma A101 port 1 [slot:4 bus:4 span:1] <wanpipe1>
switchtype=euroisdn
context=from-pstn
group=0
echocancel=yes
faxdetect=incoming
signalling=pri_net
channel =>1-15,17-31
```

/etc/dahdi/system.conf

```
#autogenerated by /usr/sbin/wancfg_dahdi do not hand edit
#autogenrated on 2014-02-21
#Dahdi Channels Configurations 
#For detailed Dahdi options, view /etc/dahdi/system.conf.bak
loadzone=us
defaultzone=us

#Sangoma A101 port 1 [slot:4 bus:4 span:1] <wanpipe1>
span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
bchan=1-15,17-31
echocanceller=mg2,1-15,17-31
hardhdlc=16



#Sangoma AFT-600 [slot:4 bus:6 span:2] <wanpipe2>
fxsks=32
echocanceller=mg2,32
fxsks=33
echocanceller=mg2,33
fxsks=34
echocanceller=mg2,34
fxsks=35
echocanceller=mg2,35
fxoks=36
echocanceller=mg2,36
```

/etc/wanpipe/wanpipe1.conf

```
#================================================
# WANPIPE1 Configuration File
#================================================
#
# Date: Wed Dec  6 20:29:03 UTC 2006
#
# Note: This file was generated automatically
#       by /usr/local/sbin/setup-sangoma program.
#
#       If you want to edit this file, it is
#       recommended that you use wancfg program
#       to do so.
#================================================
# Sangoma Technologies Inc.
#================================================

[devices]
wanpipe1 = WAN_AFT_TE1, Comment

[interfaces]
w1g1 = wanpipe1, , TDM_VOICE, Comment

[wanpipe1]
CARD_TYPE   = AFT
S514CPU     = A
CommPort    = PRI
AUTO_PCISLOT    = NO
PCISLOT     = 4
PCIBUS      = 4
FE_MEDIA    = E1
FE_LCODE    = HDB3
FE_FRAME    = CRC4
FE_LINE     = 1
TE_CLOCK    = NORMAL
TE_REF_CLOCK    = 0
TE_SIG_MODE     = CCS
TE_HIGHIMPEDANCE    = NO
TE_RX_SLEVEL    = 430
HW_RJ45_PORT_MAP = DEFAULT
LBO         = 120OH
FE_TXTRISTATE   = NO
MTU         = 1500
UDPPORT     = 9000
TTL     = 255
IGNORE_FRONT_END    = NO
TDMV_SPAN       = 1
TDMV_DCHAN      = 16
TE_AIS_MAINTENANCE = NO         #NO: defualt  YES: Start port in AIS Blue Alarm and keep line down
                                #wanpipemon -i w1g1 -c Ttx_ais_off to disable AIS maintenance mode
                                #wanpipemon -i w1g1 -c Ttx_ais_on to enable AIS maintenance mode  
TDMV_HW_DTMF        = YES       # YES: receive dtmf events from hardware
TDMV_HW_FAX_DETECT      = YES       # YES: receive fax 1100hz events from hardware
HWEC_OPERATION_MODE     = OCT_NORMAL    # OCT_NORMAL: echo cancelation enabled with nlp (default) 
                                        # OCT_SPEECH: improves software tone detection by disabling NLP (echo possible)
                                        # OCT_NO_ECHO:disables echo cancelation but allows VQE/tone functions. 
HWEC_DTMF_REMOVAL       = NO    # NO: default  YES: remove dtmf out of incoming media (must have hwdtmf enabled)
HWEC_NOISE_REDUCTION    = NO    # NO: default  YES: reduces noise on the line - could break fax
HWEC_ACUSTIC_ECHO       = NO    # NO: default  YES: enables acustic echo cancelation
HWEC_NLP_DISABLE        = NO    # NO: default  YES: guarantees software tone detection (possible echo)   
HWEC_TX_AUTO_GAIN       = 0     # 0: disable   -40-0: default tx audio level to be maintained (-20 default)
HWEC_RX_AUTO_GAIN       = 0     # 0: disable   -40-0: default tx audio level to be maintained (-20 default)  
HWEC_TX_GAIN            = 0     # 0: disable   -24-24: db values to be applied to tx signal
HWEC_RX_GAIN            = 0     # 0: disable   -24-24: db values to be applied to tx signal

[w1g1]
ACTIVE_CH   = ALL
TDMV_HWEC   = YES
MTU         = 8
```

I tried to talk with the telco, but they don't seem to be familiar with Asterisk. All they told me is I need to declare the phone numbers that they gave me on my PBX. But I don't know how to do that in Asterisk, and from all what I read, there is no need for such a declaration.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually it did work.I did several tests by changing the callerid, and it turned out I had to remove the first 0 from the phone number. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your answer is unclear.

> It was initially pri_cpe but I had to change it to pri_cpe after searching on the internet.

You have to negotiate about it with you provider. Typically provider sets `pri_net` on its side (it means provider's equipment is a source for syncronization), so customer has to set `pri_cpe`.

Full debug is full listing from Asterisk CLI (when `core set verbose=9` and `core set debug=9`).

Answer (score -1):

delete the crc4 from the system.conf 
because the card already use the crc checking

Comment: Given the OP's comment of having solved this by changing the dialed number, it would appear this can't be the solution.